# how to handle login and logout in an android app

Tags: android

```
Android Studio 3.4.0
```

I have app that when starts up will show an `login activity`. The user will login by sending username and password and will receive a JWT for authorization.

I have stored this authorization token in shared preferences. When they logout I will remove the authorization token from shared preferences.

However, when the user starts the app, I want to be able to check if the authorization token is stored and if its not show them the `login activity` or if it does exist allow them to go to the `home activity`.

So it seems I have to have a activity that will be a loading activity that will do the checking and decide which activity will be started.

However, as checking the shared preferences will be a very quick operation I don't really want to show any UI, as it will be pointless if just flashes passed and goes to the next activity.

Is there any way to have some headless activity that will just do the checking but don't display any UI.

Is there anyway to do the checking in the `Login activity` before inflating a layout?

I am not doing any facebook, google, or any social media login.

Just wondering what is the best practice to handle this.

Comment: hello @ant2009 there are many method to do this like you can run the service but its not a good way. i think shared preferences is the best way for these types of checking . i am using it too

Comment: you should use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"` and call  `finish()` after you are done in  `onCreate()`

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar workflow in my application.  The way I do it is the following.  Login activity's layout is initialised to a "Loading please wait" view. With that displayed, I use an AsyncTask to check the stored token, validate it with the back-end server and then either navigate to the main home activity or replace the "loading" fragment with a fragment containing the login form.

Answer (score 1):

Just check it in your home activity in `onCreate()` right before `setContentView()` like this:

`if (preferenceHelper.getAccessToken().isEmpty()) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@HomeActivity, LoginActivity::class.java))
            finish()
            return
}`

And it won't cause any flashes to appear.